# req.user is undefined in passportjs even when credentials is included

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, passport.js, session-cookies

I'm trying to send user information from front end after being google authenticated to the backend. However, even when I included credentials, the user information is not being sent to the backend which is strange. I'm thinking this might be a same site issue but I'm not totally sure and am not even sure of how to go about fixing that problem. If somebody can help me I would appreciate it.

This is the request being sent from the frontend:

```
export const checkLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/checkLogin",
  // function has empty argument parameter
  async () => {
    const url = "http://localhost:3001/auth/profile";
    const user = await fetch(url, {
      credentials: "include",
    }).then((response) => response.json());
    return user;
  }
);
```

This is the code in the backend for google authentication. But the problem is that in the /profile route we are not getting any information related to the user. It is only "undefined" which I'm not sure why.

```
authRouter.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.user);
  if (req.user) {
    res.send({
      redirectLink: "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
      user: req.user,
    });
  } else {
    res.send({
      redirectLink: "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
      user: null,
    });
  }
});

authRouter.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["profile"],
  })
); // passport knows to authenticate with google

authRouter.get(
  "/google/redirect",
  passport.authenticate("google"),
  (req, res) => {
    // in this step google send back the info with a code that can then be used
    // by the application to pull data from the user on google
    console.log(req.user);
    res.redirect("http://127.0.0.1:5173"); // go back to the home page
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I got it. I solved this by changing the Vite configuration for the hosting. Instead of hosting it using 127.0.0.1, I changed it to verbatim, which is then localhost. I guess this is like same-site cookie problem.

If anyone runs into this problem you can change this in the vite.config file. The link to do this is here:

https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-host